# Javascript Blob document with html tags to be saved with formatting

Tags: javascript, html, blob, doc

I am having some text like below to be saved in a downloadable doc format using javascript blob.

```
<p style='font-size:18px'>Hello</p>
```

Once the download happens I want the doc to show just show formatted '`Hello`' without any html tags. In *ubuntu* this works very well. 
But when I open the same doc in *windows* or *google docs*, I still see html tags.
Is there a way where I can do this formatting at Blob level itself. Below is the way Iam creating blob object.

```
var file = new Blob([val], {type: "octet/stream"});
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: the OS should not matter, post your code.

Answer (score 3):

Try adjusting `type` of `Blob` to `"text/html"` , using `URL.objectCreateURL()` as file object reference for download

```js
var val = "<div>abc</div>";

var file = new Blob([val], {
  type: "text/html"
});
// file object reference
var download = URL.createObjectURL(file);

var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = download;
a.download = "file-" + new Date().getTime();
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click()
```

Comment: I tried with the below. But even then with google docs I see the html tags                                                                              var a = document.getElementById("a");
var file = new Blob([val], {type: "text/html"});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

Comment: @Indraja See stacksnippets at updated post .  _"with google docs "_ Not certain how google docs renders `html` ?

Comment: The document is in .doc format. I tried opening it in windows OS. I see the html tags. In Ubuntu I see formatted text without html tags. Is there any other blob parameters which need to be set for this?

Comment: @Indraja See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624485/how-to-convert-html-file-to-word