# How to convert git repo into word document?

Tags: git, ms-word

I'm working on a thesis and need to paste all my code from the project into the appendix of the paper.  The code is currently stored in a git repository.  Is there an easy way to do this without copying and pasting the code from every single file in the repository into individual code blocks?

Comment: Can you not link them to your repo online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to include only a link, or, with Latex, a [gitinfo2 tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289290) (a precise reference to a commit)

You would then only copy-paste in your annex only the relevant *extract* of your Git repo code.

But if you must, you can transform a source code into an html with syntax highlighting colors using [`ansi2html`](https://github.com/ralphbean/ansi2html).
And then for each file, [convert it to a word document with pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22910356/6309)

You can apply that to the [list of files in your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15606995/6309):

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```